# how can I get the child nodes of the <location> section in web.config?

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config, location

I know the name of the **HttpHandler** and I need to get the **location** section that contain this handler. So I need to get all **location** sections in my web.config, then get the HttpHandlers section and check if its name is equal to those I need:

```
<location path="myhandler">
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="Handler" type="location_element.MyHandler,location_element"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I found how to get the **location** section:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
ConfigurationLocationCollection locations = config.Locations;
foreach (ConfigurationLocation location in locations)
{
    //code
}
```

But the **location** has only Path property and I can't get the child elements of this section. I found that the way is to use [IConfigurationSectionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler.aspx) and here is the description how to create [custom configuration handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228056.aspx). But the problem is that **location** section is not custom section so I can't make it use my own sectionHandler like it's done in the MSDN example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call the `OpenConfiguration()` method to open the inner configuration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationlocation.openconfiguration.aspx